# How can I determine the direction of turn?

Tags: mathematics, rotation, angles

I want a function that gives me the turn direction for my object (`1` or `-1`)

I have two angles

**1 - current rotation(A)**

0 <= A <= 360

**2 - target rotation(B)**

0 <= B <= 360

```
int turnSide = FindTurnSide(A, B);
Myobject.rotation += turnSpeed * turnSide;

public int FindTurnSide(int A, int B){
    //Find the closest side direction for return
    //return 1 for right side
    //return -1 for left side
}
```

The function should find the closest side for turn. And it should return `1` (turn right) or `-1` (turn left).

How can I implement the `FindTurnSide` function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [rotating an object from sourceAngle to destAngle, both 0-359, clockwise or counter clockwise?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11905/rotating-an-object-from-sourceangle-to-destangle-both-0-359-clockwise-or-count)

Comment: You might find my answer on stackoverflow helpful: [How to gradually rotate an object to face another turning the shortest distance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846775/7846933#7846933)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: The answer is now correct, you had to add 360 in case of `diff` negative

You just have to look at the difference between the two angles. It it is between 0 and 180, you turn left (anticlockwise), otherwise right.

```
int FindTurnSide(int current, int target)
{
     int diff = target - current;
     if(diff < 0)
         diff += 360;
     if(diff > 180)
          return -1; // left turn
     else
          return 1; // right turn
}
```

Comment: one line code for fun ;) -> return ((target-current+360)%360 - 180>0) ? -1 : 1

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
public static class MathF
{
    public const float TwoPi = Math.Pi * 2.0f;
    public const float RadAngle180 = Math.Pi;
    public const float RadAngle360 = TwoPi;

    public static float NormalizeAngle(float var)
    {
        if (var >= 0.0f && var < RadAngle360) return var;

        if (var < 0.0f)
            var = RadAngle360 + (var % RadAngle360);
        else
            var = var % RadAngle360;

        return var;
    }

    public static float TurnDir(float val1, float val2)
    {
        val1 = MathF.NormalizeAngle(val1);
        val2 = MathF.NormalizeAngle(val2);
        if (val1 == val2) return 0.0f;

        if (Math.Abs(val1 - val2) > RadAngle180)
        {
            if (val1 > val2) return 1.0f;
            else return -1.0f;
        }
        else
        {
            if (val1 > val2) return -1.0f;
            else return 1.0f;
        }
    }

    public static float CircularDist(float v1, float v2)
    {
        float vTemp = System.Math.Abs(NormalizeAngle(v1) - NormalizeAngle(v2));
        if (vTemp * 2.0f <= RadAngle360)
            return vTemp;
        else
            return RadAngle360 - vTemp;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it is not useful for performance :/