# Find range between two signed 180° angles

Tags: unity, angles

How can I find the angle between two angles that go from -180 to 180 degrees?

I would like to do :

```
if (angleDiff > 90)
{
    // The angle is bigger than 90 degrees... 
}
```

I tried subtracting them but that doesn't seem to work. Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing angles and working out the difference](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4467/comparing-angles-and-working-out-the-difference)

Comment: Your grammar was correct without the extra "s" 

Answer (score 1):

[Unity has a built-in function for this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.DeltaAngle.html):

> public static float **DeltaAngle**(float **current**, float **target**);
>
> **Description**
>
> ---
>
> Calculates the shortest difference between two given angles given in degrees.

So you can write...

```
if ( Mathf.Abs(Mathf.DeltaAngle(angleA, angleB)) > 90f ) { ... }
```

Don't forget to search for past answers and read the documentation when you have questions about common tasks like this. It's almost guaranteed you're not the first one to try to solve this problem.